# Tetris game for Windows improved version

Tags: c++, object-oriented, windows, tetris

About a month ago I made a Tetris game for Windows.  After a [helpful review](/q/216333), I improved the code. I want to hear again an opinion about the implementation, how readable the code is, new mistakes or anything that will improve the quality of the code.

#### Action.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef ACTIONS_H
#define ACTIONS_H

/*
    Possible actions that a player can do
*/

class Action
{
public:
    static constexpr char moveLEFT{ 'a' };
    static constexpr char moveRIGHT{ 'd' };
    static constexpr char moveDOWN{ 's' };
    static constexpr char rotateLEFT{ 'q' };
    static constexpr char rotateRIGHT{ 'e' };
};

#endif // !ACTIONS_H
```

#### Coordinates.cpp

```
#include "Coordinates.h"

Coordinates::Coordinates(int x, int y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

Coordinates& Coordinates::operator=(const Coordinates &coord)
{
    if (this != &coord)
    {
        this->x = coord.x;
        this->y = coord.y;
    }
    return *this;
}

int Coordinates::getX()
{
    return x;
}

int Coordinates::getY()
{
    return y;
}

void Coordinates::setX(const int &x)
{
    this->x = x;
}

void Coordinates::setY(const int &y)
{
    this->y = y;
}

void Coordinates::moveCoordinatesInADirection(char direction)
{
    switch (direction)
    {
    case Action::moveLEFT:
        y--;
        break;
    case Action::moveRIGHT:
        y++;
        break;
    case Action::moveDOWN:
        x++;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void Coordinates::Draw()
{
    MoveTo(x + Drawable::startPositionX, y + Drawable::startPositionY);
    cout << form;
}

void Coordinates::DeleteDraw()
{
    MoveTo(x + Drawable::startPositionX, y + Drawable::startPositionY);
    cout << " ";
}
```

#### Coordinates.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef COORDINATES_H
#define COORDINATES_H

#include "Actions.h"
#include "Drawable.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Coordinates : public Drawable
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    static constexpr char form{ '*' };

public:
    Coordinates(int x = 0, int y = 0);
    Coordinates& operator =(const Coordinates &coord);
    int getX();
    int getY();
    void setX(const int &x);
    void setY(const int &y);
    // Methods using a coordinate
    void moveCoordinatesInADirection(char direction);
    void Draw() override;
    void DeleteDraw() override;
};

#endif // !Coordinates_H
```

#### Difficulty.cpp

```
#include "Difficulty.h"

int Difficulty::increaseSpeedAfterXTilesPlayed = 20;
int Difficulty::speedOfTiles = 600;

void Difficulty::setDifficulty(char numberOfDifficulty)
{
    switch (numberOfDifficulty)
    {
    //Easy
    case '1':
        increaseSpeedAfterXTilesPlayed = 20;
        speedOfTiles = 600;
        break;
    //Normal
    case '2':
        increaseSpeedAfterXTilesPlayed = 15;
        speedOfTiles = 400;
        break;
    //Hard
    case '3':
        increaseSpeedAfterXTilesPlayed = 10;
        speedOfTiles = 200;
        break;
    //Impossible
    case '4':
        increaseSpeedAfterXTilesPlayed = 5;
        speedOfTiles = 100;
        break;
    }
}

void Difficulty::increaseSpeedafterXTiles(int& counterNumberOfTilesPlayed)
{
    if ((counterNumberOfTilesPlayed == Difficulty::increaseSpeedAfterXTilesPlayed)
        && (Difficulty::speedOfTiles > 20))
    {

        Difficulty::speedOfTiles = Difficulty::speedOfTiles - 20;
        counterNumberOfTilesPlayed = 0;
    }
}
```

#### Difficulty.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef DIFFICULTY_H
#define DEFFICULTY_H

class Difficulty
{
public:
    static int increaseSpeedAfterXTilesPlayed;
    static int speedOfTiles;

public:
    static void setDifficulty(char numberOfDifficulty);
    static void increaseSpeedafterXTiles(int& counterNumberOfTilesPlayed);
};
#endif // !DIFFICULTY_H
```

#### Drawable.cpp

```
#include "Drawable.h"

int Drawable::getstartPositionX()
{
    return startPositionX;
}

void Drawable::hideCursor()
{
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO info = { 100,FALSE };
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &info);
}

void Drawable::MoveTo(const int &x, const int &y)
{
    COORD coord = { startPositionY + y,startPositionX + x };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
```

#### Drawable.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef DRAWABLE_H
#define DRAWABLE_H

#include <windows.h>

class Drawable
{
protected:
    //The position where the table game will be displayed in console
    static constexpr int startPositionX{ 10 };
    static constexpr int startPositionY{ 25 };

public:
    static int getstartPositionX();
    static void hideCursor();
    static void MoveTo(const int &x,const int &y);
    virtual void Draw() = 0;
    virtual void DeleteDraw() = 0;
};

#endif // !DRAWABLE_H
```

#### Source.cpp

```
#include "Table.h"

int main()
{
    Table a;

    try {
        a.startGame();
    }
    catch (...) 
    {
        // In case player loses
        Drawable::MoveTo(Drawable::getstartPositionX() + Table::numberOfLines + 1, 0);
        cout << "\n" << "Good job, you made " << a.score * 1000 << " points.\n";
    }
}
```

#### Table.cpp

```
#include "Table.h"

Table::Table()
{
    // When you start the game the table is empty and the score is 0
    score = 0;

    for (int currentLine = 0; currentLine < numberOfLines; currentLine++)
    {
        for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < numberOfColumns; currentColumn++)
        {
            table[currentLine][currentColumn] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void Table::informationAboutGame()
{
    // General informations about the game and setting the difficulty the player wants to play on

    cout << "\n\n\n\t This is a tetris game.The controls for the game are:\n";
    cout << "\n\t a - move the tile left";
    cout << "\n\t d - move the tile right";
    cout << "\n\t s - move the tile down";
    cout << "\n\t e - rotate the tile right";
    cout << "\n\t q - rotate the tile left";
    cout << "\n\n\t The game has 3 difficulties: ";
    cout << "\n\t 1. Easy";
    cout << "\n\t 2. Normal";
    cout << "\n\t 3. Hard";
    cout << "\n\t 4. Impossible";
    cout << "\n\n\t Introduce the number of the difficulty you want to play on and good luck: ";

    char numberOfDifficulty = _getch();

    while ((numberOfDifficulty != '1') && (numberOfDifficulty != '2') && 
        (numberOfDifficulty != '3') && (numberOfDifficulty!='4'))
    {
        cout << "\n\tInsert a number between 1-4: ";
        numberOfDifficulty = _getch();
    }

    Difficulty::setDifficulty(numberOfDifficulty);
}

void Table::checkingAndDeletingCompletedLines()
{
    // We parse the table and check if there is any line with only 1 on it, and than we delete the line
    int check = 1;

    for (int currentLine = 0; currentLine < numberOfLines; currentLine++)
    {
        check = 1;

        for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < numberOfColumns; currentColumn++)
        {
            if (table[currentLine][currentColumn] == 0)
            {
                check = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (check)
        {
            deleteCompletedLineFromTable(currentLine);
            score++;
        }
    }
}

void Table::deleteCompletedLineFromTable(const int& line)
{
    // Deleting the line which is completed
    // We need to actualize the table by replacing every line (starting from the completed line until the second line) with the previous lines
    // Also we need to draw the actualized lines in the console
    for (int currentLine = line; currentLine > 0; currentLine--)
    {
        for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < numberOfColumns; currentColumn++)
        {
            Drawable::MoveTo(currentLine + Drawable::startPositionX, currentColumn + Drawable::startPositionY);
            if (table[currentLine - 1][currentColumn] == 0)
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
            else {
                cout << Coordinates::form;
            }

            table[currentLine][currentColumn] = table[currentLine - 1][currentColumn];
        }
    }

    for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < numberOfColumns; currentColumn++)
    {
        Drawable::MoveTo(0 + Drawable::startPositionX, currentColumn + Drawable::startPositionY);
        cout << " ";
        table[0][currentColumn] = 0;
    }
}

void Table::moveTileDownAutomatically()
{
    //Moving the actual tile down every and checking if the player wants to make a move(right, left, down) or rotate(right, left) the tile
    actualTile.Draw();

    int counterTime = 0;

    do {
        counterTime = 0;

        while (counterTime <= Difficulty::speedOfTiles)
        {
            if (_kbhit())             // if the player presses a key on keyboard
            {
                possibleMoves(counterTime);
            }

            Sleep(1);
            counterTime = counterTime + 1;
        }

        if (checkIfCanMoveInADirection(Action::moveDOWN))
        {
            actualTile.DeleteDraw();
            moveTileInADirection(Action::moveDOWN);
            actualTile.Draw();
        }
        else 
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
}

void Table::moveTileInADirection(char direction)
{
    // To move the tile in a direction we need to :
    // - delete the previous tile from the game table
    // - move the tile to the new coordinates
    // - actualizate the game table
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        table[actualTile.getcoordX(i)][actualTile.getcoordY(i)] = 0;
    }

    actualTile.moveTileInADirection(direction);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        table[actualTile.getcoordX(i)][actualTile.getcoordY(i)] = 1;
    }
}

void Table::possibleMoves(int &counterTime)
{
    //Possible moves that can be effectuated on a tile (move and rotate)
    char direction = _getch();

    if (checkIfCanMoveInADirection(direction))
    {
        actualTile.DeleteDraw();                  // delete old tile
        moveTileInADirection(direction);          // move the tile in the direction the player wanted
        actualTile.Draw();                        // draw the new tile
        if (direction == Action::moveDOWN)
        {
            // If we move the tile down we reset the counter until the tile moves again down by itself
            counterTime = 1;
        }
    }
    // check if the player wanted to rotate the tile (right, left)
    if ((direction == Action::rotateRIGHT) || (direction == Action::rotateLEFT))
    {
        actualTile.DeleteDraw();
        rotateTileInADirection(direction);
        actualTile.Draw();
    }
}

void Table::positioningTileInTableAfterRotation()
{
    // This method is used to check and correct a tile if it goes out of boundaries of the game table after a rotation
    int index = 0;
    int checkOutOfBoundaries = 0;

    while (index < 4)
    {
        if (actualTile.getcoordY(index) < 0)
        {
            // passed left boundary of the game table
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                actualTile.setcoordY(j, actualTile.getcoordY(j) + 1);
            }
            checkOutOfBoundaries = 1;
        }

        if (actualTile.getcoordY(index) > numberOfColumns - 1)
        {
            // passed right boundary of the game table
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                actualTile.setcoordY(j, actualTile.getcoordY(j) - 1);
            }
            checkOutOfBoundaries = 1;
        }

        if (actualTile.getcoordX(index) < 0)
        {
            // passed top boundary of the game table and there are cases where the player loses
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                actualTile.setcoordX(j, actualTile.getcoordX(j) + 1);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                if ((actualTile.getcoordX(j) > 0) && (table[actualTile.getcoordX(j)][actualTile.getcoordY(j)] == 1))
                {
                    throw 0;
                }
            }
            checkOutOfBoundaries = 1;
        }

        if ((actualTile.getcoordX(index) > numberOfLines - 1) ||
            (table[actualTile.getcoordX(index)][actualTile.getcoordY(index)] == 1))
        {
            // passed the down boundary or reached a possition that is occupied
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                actualTile.setcoordX(j, actualTile.getcoordX(j) - 1);
            }
            checkOutOfBoundaries = 1;
        }

        if (checkOutOfBoundaries == 1)
        {
            index = 0;
            checkOutOfBoundaries = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            index++;
        }
    }
}

void Table::rotateTileInADirection(char direction)
{
    // To rotate the tile in a direction we need to :
    // - delete the previous tile from the game table
    // - move the tile to the new coordinates and adjust it so it doesnt pass the boundaries of the game table
    // - actualizate the game table
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        table[actualTile.getcoordX(i)][actualTile.getcoordY(i)] = 0;
    }

    actualTile.rotateTileInADirection(direction);
    positioningTileInTableAfterRotation();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        table[actualTile.getcoordX(i)][actualTile.getcoordY(i)] = 1;
    }
}

void Table::startGame()
{
    Drawable::hideCursor();
    informationAboutGame();

    DeleteDraw();
    Draw();

    int counterNumberOfTilesPlayed = 0;

    // This while will end when the player will lose
    while (true)
    {
        checkingAndDeletingCompletedLines();

        actualTile = Tiles::generateRandomTile();

        if (checkIfPlayerLost() == false)
        {
            moveTileDownAutomatically();

            counterNumberOfTilesPlayed++;
            Difficulty::increaseSpeedafterXTiles(counterNumberOfTilesPlayed);
        }
        else 
        {
            Drawable::MoveTo(Drawable::startPositionX + numberOfLines + 1, 0);
            cout << "\n" << "Good job, you made " << score * 1000 << " points.\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Table::Draw()
{
    // Method used to draw the table 
    for (int index = -1; index <= numberOfLines; index++)
    {
        MoveTo(Drawable::startPositionX + index, Drawable::startPositionY - 1);
        cout << char(219);
        MoveTo(Drawable::startPositionX + index, Drawable::startPositionY + numberOfColumns);
        cout << char(219);
    }

    for (int index = -1; index <= numberOfColumns; index++)
    {
        Drawable::MoveTo(Drawable::startPositionX - 1, Drawable::startPositionY + index);
        cout << char(219);
        Drawable::MoveTo(Drawable::startPositionX + numberOfLines, Drawable::startPositionY + index);
        cout << char(219);
    }
}


void Table::DeleteDraw()
{
    // Method used to delete the table
    system("cls");
}

bool Table::belongsToActualTile(const int& x, const int& y)
{
    //Checking if a piece(point/coordinate) of a tile belonds to the actual tile
    for (int currentCoordinate = 0; currentCoordinate < 4; currentCoordinate++)
    {
        if ((actualTile.getcoordX(currentCoordinate) == x) && (actualTile.getcoordY(currentCoordinate) == y))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool Table::checkIfCanMoveInADirection(char direction)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            // Check if the player can move left
        case Action::moveLEFT:
            if ((actualTile.getcoordY(i) - 1 < 0) ||
                ((belongsToActualTile(actualTile.getcoordX(i), actualTile.getcoordY(i) - 1)) &&
                (table[actualTile.getcoordX(i)][actualTile.getcoordY(i) - 1] == 1)))
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
            // Check if the player can move right
        case Action::moveRIGHT:
            if ((actualTile.getcoordY(i) + 1 > numberOfColumns - 1) ||
                ((belongsToActualTile(actualTile.getcoordX(i), actualTile.getcoordY(i) + 1)) &&
                (table[actualTile.getcoordX(i)][actualTile.getcoordY(i) + 1] == 1)))
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
            // Check if the player can move down
        case Action::moveDOWN:
            if ((actualTile.getcoordX(i) + 1 > numberOfLines - 1) ||
                ((belongsToActualTile(actualTile.getcoordX(i) + 1, actualTile.getcoordY(i))) &&
                (table[actualTile.getcoordX(i) + 1][actualTile.getcoordY(i)] == 1)))
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool Table::checkIfPlayerLost()
{
    for (int currentCoordinate = 0; currentCoordinate < 4; currentCoordinate++)
    {
        if (table[actualTile.getcoordX(currentCoordinate)][actualTile.getcoordY(currentCoordinate)] == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

#### Table.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef TABLE_H
#define TABLE_H

#include "Difficulty.h"
#include "Tile.h"
#include "Tiles.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <random>

class Table : public Drawable           // class that represents the game table 
{
public:
    static constexpr int  numberOfColumns{ 11 };
    static constexpr int numberOfLines{ 21 };
    long score;
private:
    int table[numberOfLines][numberOfColumns];            // the game table= a matrix with 0 if there is nothing draw in that point and 1 if there is something draw 
    Tile actualTile;         // the tile that moves in the game table(the actual tile)

public:
    Table();
    void informationAboutGame();
    void checkingAndDeletingCompletedLines();
    void deleteCompletedLineFromTable(const int& line);        // after a line from the table is completated, it will be deleted from the game table and the score will rise
    void moveTileDownAutomatically();
    void moveTileInADirection(char direction);
    void possibleMoves(int& counterTime);         // possible moves of a player (right, left, down)
    void positioningTileInTableAfterRotation();
    void rotateTileInADirection(char direction);
    void startGame();
    void Draw();
    void DeleteDraw();
    bool belongsToActualTile(const int& x, const int& y);
    bool checkIfCanMoveInADirection(char direction);
    bool checkIfPlayerLost();
};

#endif // !TABLE_H
```

#### Tile.cpp

```
#include "Tile.h"
#include "Table.h"

Tile::Tile()
{
    for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
    {
        coordTile[index].setX(0);
        coordTile[index].setY(0);
    }

    centerOfTile = -1;
}

Tile& Tile::operator=(const Tile &tile)
{
    if (this != &tile)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            this->coordTile[i] = tile.coordTile[i];
        }
        this->centerOfTile = tile.centerOfTile;
    }

    return *this;
}

/*
    A tile is in tiles.in is saved like this:
        0 0 0 2
        0 2 2 2
        0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0
    A tile stores has a array of 4 coordinates(Coordinates) and a center(int)
    In the array we will save the 4 coordinates ((0,3) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3)) that don't have the value 0 in matrix, and in the centerOfTile the center of the figure
*/

void Tile::initializationOfTile(ifstream& input)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int checkValue = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
        {
            input >> checkValue;

            if (checkValue != 0)
            {
                coordTile[counter].setX(x);
                coordTile[counter++].setY(Table::numberOfColumns / 2 + 2 - y);  // Setting the coordinate for Y in the middle of the table

                if ((x == 1) && (y == 2))
                {
                    centerOfTile = counter - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int Tile::getcoordX(const int &position)
{
    return coordTile[position].getX();
}

int Tile::getcoordY(const int &position)
{
    return coordTile[position].getY();
}

int Tile::getcenterOfTile(const int &position)
{
    return centerOfTile;
}

void Tile::setcoordX(const int &position, const int &x)
{
    coordTile[position].setX(x);
}

void Tile::setcoordY(const int &position, const int &y)
{
    coordTile[position].setY(y);
}

void Tile::setcenterOfTile(const int &centerOfTile)
{
    this->centerOfTile = centerOfTile;
}

void Tile::moveTileInADirection(char direction)
{
    for (int currentCoordinate = 0; currentCoordinate < 4; currentCoordinate++)
    {
        coordTile[currentCoordinate].moveCoordinatesInADirection(direction);
    }
}

void Tile::rotateTileInADirection(char direction)
{
    int dir = 0;

    switch (direction)
    {
    case Action::rotateRIGHT:           // to rotate the tile to the right we need +90* check formula down
        dir = +90;
        break;
    case Action::rotateLEFT:           // to rotate the tile to the left we need -90* check formula down
        dir = -90;
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }

    // If the tile can be rotated
    if (centerOfTile != -1)
    {
        double centerOfTileX = coordTile[centerOfTile].getX();
        double centerOfTileY = coordTile[centerOfTile].getY();

        double tileX = 0;
        double tileY = 0;

        // Rotate every piece(point/coordinate) from the tile with 90*(to right) or -90*(to left) depends on dir
        for (int currentCoordinate = 0; currentCoordinate < 4; currentCoordinate++)
        {
            tileX = (double) coordTile[currentCoordinate].getX();
            tileY = (double) coordTile[currentCoordinate].getY();

            coordTile[currentCoordinate].setX((int)round((tileX - centerOfTileX) * cos((3.14 * dir) / 180) +
                (tileY - centerOfTileY) * sin((3.14 * dir) / 180) + centerOfTileX));
            coordTile[currentCoordinate].setY((int)round((centerOfTileX - tileX) * sin((3.14 * dir) / 180) +
                (tileY - centerOfTileY) * cos((3.14 * dir) / 180) + centerOfTileY));
        }
    }
}

void Tile::Draw()
{
    for (int currentCoordinate = 0; currentCoordinate < 4; currentCoordinate++)
    {
        coordTile[currentCoordinate].Draw();             // Drawing the tile by drawing every piece (point/coordinate) of it
    }
}

void Tile::DeleteDraw()
{
    for (int currentCoordinate = 0; currentCoordinate < 4; currentCoordinate++)
    {
        coordTile[currentCoordinate].DeleteDraw();      // Deleting the tile by deleting every piece (point/coordinate) of it
    }
}
```

#### Tile.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef TILE_H
#define TILE_H

#include "Coordinates.h"
#include "Drawable.h"
#include <fstream>

// Class that represents a tile and all its methods
class Tile : public Drawable
{
private:
    // Every tile is composed of 4 coordinates and a center
    Coordinates coordTile[4];
    int centerOfTile;

public:
    Tile();
    Tile& operator=(const Tile &tile);
    void initializationOfTile(ifstream& input);
    // Getter and setter
    int getcenterOfTile(const int &position);
    int getcoordX(const int &position);
    int getcoordY(const int &position);
    void setcenterOfTile(const int &centerOfTile);
    void setcoordX(const int &position, const int &x);
    void setcoordY(const int &position, const int &y);
    // Methods using a tile
    void moveTileInADirection(char direction);          // Moves the tile in a specific direction (right, left, down)
    void rotateTileInADirection(char direction);       // Rotates the tile in a specific direction (right, left)
    void Draw() override;                             // Overrides function Draw() from Drawable() and is used to draw the tile in the game table
    void DeleteDraw() override;                      // Overrides function DeleteDraw() from Drawable() and is used to delete the tile from the game table
};

#endif // !TILE_H
```

#### Tiles.cpp

```
#include "Tiles.h"


int Tiles::numberOfTiles = initializationOfNumberOfTiles();
Tile* Tiles::figures = initializationOfFigures();

int Tiles::initializationOfNumberOfTiles()
{
    int numberOfTiles = 0;

    ifstream input("tiles.in");
    input >> numberOfTiles;
    input.close();

    return numberOfTiles;
}

Tile* Tiles::initializationOfFigures()
{
    Tile* figures;
    int numberOfTiles = 0;

    ifstream input("tiles.in");
    input >> numberOfTiles;
    figures = new Tile[numberOfTiles];

    for (int currentTile = 0; currentTile < numberOfTiles; currentTile++)
    {
        figures[currentTile].initializationOfTile(input);
    }

    //The center of a line respectively a square is different than the other figures
    figures[0].setcenterOfTile(2);
    figures[3].setcenterOfTile(-1);

    input.close();

    return figures;
}

Tile Tiles::generateRandomTile()
{
    Tile randomTile;
    int randomNumber = 0;

    random_device random;
    uniform_int_distribution<int>dist(0, numberOfTiles - 1);

    randomNumber = dist(random);
    randomTile = figures[randomNumber];

    return randomTile;
}

Tiles::~Tiles()
{
    delete[] figures;
}
```

#### Tiles.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef TILES_H
#define TILES_H

#include "Tile.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <random>

class Tiles                 // Contains the number of tiles and the tiles possible
{
private:
    static int numberOfTiles;
    static Tile* figures;

private:
    static int initializationOfNumberOfTiles();
    static Tile* initializationOfFigures();
    ~Tiles();

public:
    static Tile generateRandomTile();
};

#endif // !TILES_H
```

#### tiles.in

```
7

2 2 2 2 
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0

0 2 0 0
0 2 2 2
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0

0 0 0 2
0 2 2 2
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0

0 2 2 0
0 2 2 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0

0 0 2 2
0 2 2 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0

0 0 2 0
0 2 2 2
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0

0 2 2 0
0 0 2 2
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

The code is also available: [Github Tetris game](https://github.com/FirescuOvidiu/Tetris-game-for-Windows)

**Edit**: I will respond to both commentaries in this edit, thanks you both for the time spend to respond. 
So, I managed to move almost all includes in the .cpp files, rearranged the methods and members in classes (pub, prot, priv), modified `const& int` in `int`, used const wherever I could, deleted the copy constructor and other destructors that I didn't need, gave better names to the variables, used namespace instead of some classes that had only static methods, made better comments. I didn't modify the prefix for members, because it seemed harder to read the code, and I tried to use namespace on every class but than I modified back without namespace because don't know how to get rid of x::x::A(); and it makes the lines so long and hard to read, tried to don't use namespace std; anywhere, I used it only in one file .cpp out of 15files. Replaced every array with a std::vector, managed to get rid of the try catch block. In Difficulty.cpp I had `int& counterNumberOfTilesPlayed;` because I change this value in the function. Besides that I had before on every function `const type&`.
I will get rid of the namespace std; totally and try to find a way to use namespace tomorrow I think. Besides that I did everyother observations. I don't know if I should add the code again in this thread, I updated the github and all the changes can be seen in the link above.
**Edit 2:** @Sandro4912 managed to do the last advice you gave me that I didn't do last night and wrapped all functions and classes into a namespace, stopped using namespace std;

Comment: Unfortunately your question is off-topic as of now, as the code to be reviewed must be [present in the question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308) Code behind links is considered non-reviewable. Please add the code you want reviewed in your question. Thanks!

Comment: I have 15 different files (.h and .cpp) because I separated declaration and implementation and put one class per file. Should I copy all the code from all the 15 files in the question ?

Comment: You could do that or just the most important classes and their interfaces. The more code you supply, generally the more comprehensive and useful the reviews.

Comment: I understand I will edit the question tomorrow morning with the code and everything.

Answer (score 2):

No time to read through all the code for now. So just some random observations.

**In Coordinates.h:**

**Include as less as poissible in headers:** You include `iostream` but it is only needed in `Coordinates.cpp`. Generally you should include as less as possible in header files. If
you include `iostream` in the header every class which includes `Coordinates.h` also includes `iostream` even if it is not necessary. This leads to longer compilation times. Same for `Actions.h`

**Follow the order public protected private in classes:**
You want to read the most important parts of a class at first. Normally this is the functions the user can use, not implementation specific details like private members.

**Pass built in types by value**: It is cheaper to copy an int than to pass it by const reference. So in youre setX method you should just pass it as `int` not `const int&`

**Use const when possible**: `getX()` does not modify its object so declare it const. You should always use const for functions who don't modify the object.

**Don't declare a Copy Constructor on trivial classes**: Youre class only has int data members. Therefore youre compiler will happily generate the copy constructor for you. Theres absolutely no need to declare it. Besides if you declare a copy constructor you should also declare the other classes of the rule of five: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three. In the case of youre class its not necessary.

**Be consistent with naming**: I would not use capital letters for functions. So `Draw()` and `DeleteDraw()` should be `draw()` and `deleteDraw()`.

**Don't use namespace std:** Especially not in a header file. You force youre user to import all the namespace std if they ever include youre header file. It really is very bad style to use namespace std. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

**Use a namespace**: You should wrap all youre functions and classes in its own namespace to prevent nameclashes. Otherwise if you write a programm with other libraries theres the danger nameclases happen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211827/why-and-how-should-i-use-namespaces-in-c

**Use a prefix for members::** This is a bit controversial but i would use a prefix m for member variables so they are clearly visible as member variables. It also elimnates the need for `this->` in youe `coordinates.cpp`

**Avoid unessary comments:**: The comment in youre class `Methods using a coordinate` is just a bloat its pretty obvious that these methods do sth with Coordinates because they are in the Coordinates class.

Putting everything together we get this:

**Coordinate.h**

```
#ifndef COORDINATES_H
#define COORDINATES_H

#include "Drawable.h"

namespace tetris {

    class Coordinates : public Drawable
    {
    public:
        Coordinates(int x = 0, int y = 0);

        int getX() const;
        int getY() const;

        void setX(int x);
        void setY(int y);

        // Methods using a coordinate
        void moveCoordinatesInADirection(char direction);
        void draw() override;
        void deleteDraw() override;

    private:
        static constexpr char form{ '*' };

        int mX;
        int mY;
    };
}

#endif
```

**Coordinates.cpp**

```
#include "Coordinates.h"

#include "Actions.h"

#include <iostream>

namespace tetris {

    Coordinates::Coordinates(int x, int y)
        :mX{x}, mY{y}
    {
    }

    int Coordinates::getX() const
    {
        return mX;
    }

    int Coordinates::getY() const
    {
        return mY;
    }

    void Coordinates::setX(int x)
    {
        mX = x;
    }

    void Coordinates::setY(int y)
    {
        mY = y;
    }

    void Coordinates::moveCoordinatesInADirection(char direction)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
        case Action::moveLEFT:
            mY--;
            break;
        case Action::moveRIGHT:
            mY++;
            break;
        case Action::moveDOWN:
            mX++;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    void Coordinates::draw()
    {
        MoveTo(mX + Drawable::startPositionX, mY + Drawable::startPositionY);
        std::cout << form;
    }

    void Coordinates::deleteDraw()
    {
        MoveTo(mX + Drawable::startPositionX, mY + Drawable::startPositionY);
        std::cout << " ";
    }
}
```

I will probaly add more to this answer later when I have time.

Comment: Thanks again @Sandro4912 for taking your free time to help me improve even more the quality of the code and learn. I posted an response to your answer in the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Action.h**

1. The `Action` class only contains public static data members. While it's not illegal, a class might not be the best way to go about it. Consider using `struct`, which is the same as a `class` but has `public`as the default access specifier. Or even better, don't use a `class` or `struct` and instead, wrap it inside a namespace, which seems perfect for this kind of thing.

```
namespace Action
{
  static constexpr char moveLEFT{ 'a' };
  static constexpr char moveRIGHT{ 'd' };
  static constexpr char moveDOWN{ 's' };
  static constexpr char rotateLEFT{ 'q' };
  static constexpr char rotateRIGHT{ 'e' };    
}
```

You can then use it the same way as you're doing now. `Action::moveLeft` et cetera.

**Coordinate.cpp**

1. Use initializer list instead of setting the members in the body of the constructor. Only it doesn't really matter *in this case*, it's still a good idea to do so. [See here why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list)

```
Coordinates::Coordinates(int x_, int y_): x(x_), y(y_) { /* empty */ }
```

2. Make your getters `const`. In fact, you should mark all methods that are not modifying your data members `const`.

```
int Coordinates::getX() const
{
    return x;
}

int Coordinates::getY() const
{
  return y;
}
```

3. You don't need to do `const int& x` in the `setX()` function. The cost of copying an `int` is negligible. `void setX(int x)` is fine. We pass by reference when we want to change the value of the argument `void changeValueOfX(int& x)` or when a structure is large enough the copying it incurs a non-negligible penalty `void doStuffWith2DVector(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vec)`.

**Coordinate.h**

1. Since all your constructor is doing is setting the value, you could just put the initializer list in this header instead of putting it in the cpp file.

`Coordinates(int x_ = 0, int y_ = 0): x(x_), y(y_) {}`

2. `using namespace std;` is frowned upon, and using it inside a header is a big no-no. Remember that all the code in the header file is literally copy-pasted whenever you do `#include "Coordinates.h`. That means every file where you include this file will contain the line `using namespace std;` and can lead to some nasty bugs if you're not careful.
3. Don't include headers when you don't need them. The header is not using `iostream`. Instead, include the file when in the `Coordinates.cpp` file, when you actually do need to use it.

**Difficulty.cpp**

1. Again, no need to do `int& counterNumberOfTilesPlayed`. Just do `int counterNumberOfTilesPlayed`. Also, your argument list is inconsistent. In the earlier file you did `const int& x` and now you're doing `int& counterNumberOfTilesPlayed`, when you're not changing the value of the argument in either of those.

**Difficulty.h**

1. Spelling error in the include guard.
2. Again, all your class is containing is public static members and member functions. Wrap them inside a namespace rather than a class. C++ contains OOP features, but we don't have to use it all the time.

**Drawable.cpp**

1. Mark methods as `const`.
2. Don't need to `const int& x`, et cetera.

**Drawable.h**

1. You don't need `windows.h` in this file. Move it over to the implementation.

**Source.cpp**

1. I haven't actually looked at the implementation of your code, but there is surely a better way to realize when a player loses than a try catch block. Rethink your logic. A try catch block to decide whether a player loses seems, to be honest, ugly.

**Table.cpp**

1. Use member initializer list in the constructor to sets values of your data members.

```
Table::Table(): score(0)
{
    ...

}
```

**Table.h**

1. Move the non-required headers into the implementation.

**General**

1. A lot of your classes contain only or mostly static data. You should reevaluate whether a class is the best choice.
2. Your naming of methods and members is too verbose. While variables should always be named to describe their purpose, too long a variable name can be cumbersome, for the person writing the code and the person who will read it.

A few examples:

- `moveCoordinatesInADirection(char direction)` can be renamed `moveCoordinates(char direction)`. In both cases, the name describes what the method is doing, but the latter is shorter and more concise.
- `counterNumberOfTilesPlayed` can be renamed `numberOfTilesPlayed` or `numTilesPlayed` or even `tilesPlayed`.
- `informationAboutGame` can be renamed `gameInfo`.
- `checkingAndDeletingCompletedLines` can be renamed `deleteCompletedLines`
- `moveTileDownAutomatically` can be renamed `moveTileDown`.

Any many more..

3. Comments: I firmly believe code should be self-documenting unless a method or variable or statement requires explicit instructions or programmer's intention.

```
void moveTileInADirection(char direction);          // Moves the tile in a specific direction (right, left, down)
```

adds nothing to the source code. One could figure it out from the method prototype.

4. Consider using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of C-style arrays.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer @Rish, really helpful, I posted a response in the question. I think to do all the suggestions you posted.